# Regex that will match each specific tag that contains ../

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to find a regex that will match each specific tag that contains `../`.
I had it matching when each element was on its own line. But then there was an instance where my HTML rendered on one line causing the regex to match the whole line:

```
<body><img src="../../../img.png"><img src="../../img.png"><img src="../../img.png"><img src="..//../img.png"><img src="..../../img.png">
```

Here was the regex that I was using

```
<.*[\.]{2}[\/].*>
```

Comment: `.*` is greedy, `<.*?\.{2}\/.*?>` or `<[^<>]*?\.{2}\/[^<>]*>`

Comment: Use [**DOM**](https://eval.in/297279) to do this.

Comment: @hwnd, some explanation for your comment would be helpful.  Just saying **use something** doesn't give people the reasons to follow your comment.

Comment: Maybe you should follow up on DomDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to match only one tag per match.
Using a negative character class like below will accomplish that.

```
<[^>]*\.\./[^>]*>
```

`<` = start of tag

`[^>]*` = any number of characters that *aren't* `>`, since `>` would end the tag

`\.\./` = "`../`" with escapes for the `.` characters

`[^>]*` = same as above

`>` = end of tag

It appears you might be doing this to prevent path parenting. You should know that for a URL attribute in an HTML tag, the following tags are considered "equivalent":

```
<img src="../foo.jpg">
<img src="%2e%2e%2ffoo.jpg">
<img src="&#46;&#46;/foo.jpg">
```

That's because the `src` attribute goes through HTML entity un-escaping, and then URL un-escaping (in that order) before being used. As a result, **there are 5,832 different ways to write '../'** into an HTML tag's path attribute (18 ways to write each character times 3 characters).

Making a regex to match any of these encodings of `../` is more difficult, but still possible.

```
(\.|&#46;|(%|&#37;)(2|&#50;)([Ee]|&#69;|&#101;)){2}(/|&#47;|(%|&#37;)(2|&#50;)([Ff]|&#70;|&#102;))
```

For reference:

`&#46;` = `.` HTML escape sequence

`&#47;` = `/` HTML escape sequence

`%2E` or `%2e` = `.` URL escape sequence

`%2F` or `%2f` = `/` URL escape sequence

`&#37;` = `%` HTML escape sequence

`&#50;` = `2` HTML escape sequence

`&#69;` = `E` HTML escape sequence

`&#101;` = `e` HTML escape sequence

`&#70;` = `F` HTML escape sequence

`&#102;` = `f` HTML escape sequence

You can see why people usually say it's better to use a real HTML parser, instead of regex!

Anyway, assuming yo need this, and a full HTML parser isn't feasable, here's the version of `<[^>]*[="'/]\.\./[^>]*>` that also catches HTML and URL escaping:

```
<[^>]*[="'/](\.|&#46;|(%|&#37;)(2|&#50;)([Ee]|&#69;|&#101;)){2}(/|&#47;|(%|&#37;)(2|&#50;)([Ff]|&#70;|&#102;))[^>]*>
```

Comment: Actually my end goal is to load a document using an HTML parser, change relative paths in the document to absolute paths, and then load the document into a file on my server so that I can iframe the content and avoid the cross domain issue whilst trying to use javascript on the contents. I know it sounds like a strange way of doing things and it's unrelated to my original question but you seem quite knowledgeable and I'm curious what you think of it?

Comment: A parser is definitely the way to go, since it'll handle at least the HTML escaping for you. I use python's beautifulsoup module, and there are probably good equivalents for PHP (though I haven't used PHP much, so I couldn't suggest one). As for your goal, there are quite a few reasons to choose relative and/or absolute paths, depending on the context. I hope you're able to get everything working smoothly. =)

Answer (score 0):

Causing the `regex` to match the whole line seems you are `regex` is greedy, try this way as @Avinash Raj commented.

[image]

SEE [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cX8bN9/1)

Comment: What do your regexp do with `<img src="../../a>b.png">`.  It's allowed by xml syntax. What would it do with `<!--- <img src="../../a>b.png"> -->`  You know?

Comment: What would do with `<img src="<img src='../../a>b.png'>">`  (this is not valid xml, but it is html, not sure)

Answer (score 0):

To get the regexp you want I will try to follow a step by step approach:

- First, we need some regex that matches the beginning and end of the tag. But we must be carefull, as the tag end character `>` is allowed in single and double quote strings.  We construct first the regexp that matches these single/double quoted strings:  `([^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*`  (a sequence of: non-quote (single and double) and non end tag character, or a single quoted string, or a double quoted string)
- Now, modify it to match a single quoted string or a double quoted string that includes a `../`: `([^"'>]|"[^"]*\.\.\/[^"]*"|'[^']*\.\.\/[^']*')*`  (we can simplify it, eliminating the last `*` operator, as we will match the whole string with only **one** matching `../` inside, and we can eliminate the first option, as we will have the `../` seq inside quoted strings). We get to: `("[^"]*\.\.\/[^"]*"|'[^']*\.\.\/[^']*')`
- To get a string matching a sequence including at least one of the second strings, we concatenate the first regex at the beginning and at the end, and the other in the middle.  We get to: `([^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*("[^"]*\.\.\/[^"]*"|'[^']*\.\.\/[^']*')([^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*`
- Now, we only need to surround this regexp with the needed sequences first `<[iI][mM][gG][ \t\n]`, and after `>`, getting to:

  `<[iI][mM][gG][ \t\n]([^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*("[^"]*\.\.\/[^"]*"|'[^']*\.\.\/[^']*')([^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>`

This is the regexp we need.  See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uL0pZ7/3) If we extract the content of the second group (`$2`, `\2`, etc.) we'll get to the parameter value that matches (with the quotes included) the `../` string.

Don't try to simplify this further as `>` characters are allowed inside single and double quoted strings, and `"` are allowed in single quoted strings, and `'` are in double quoted strings.  As someone explained in another answer to this question, you cannot be greedy (using `.*` inside, as you'll eat as much input as possible before matching)  This regexp will need to match multiline tags, as these could be part of your input file.  If you have a well formed HTML file, then you'll have no problem with this regexp.

**And some final quoting**:  an HTML tag is defined by a grammar **that is regular** (it is only a regular subset of the full HTML syntax), so it is perfectly parseable with a regex (the same is not true for the complete HTML language)  A regex is by far more efficient and less resource consuming than a full HTML parser.  The caveats are that you have to write it (and to write it well) and that HTML parsers are easily found with some googling that avoid you the work of doing it, but you have to write it only once.  Regexp parsing is a one pass process that grows in complexity (for this example, at least) linearly with input text length.  You'll be advised against this by people that simply don't know how to write the right regexp or don't know how to determine is some grammar is regular.

## Note:

This regexp will match commented tags.  In case you don't want to match commented `<img>` tags, you'll have to extend your regexp a little or do a two pass to eliminate comments first, and then parse tags (the regexp that only recognizes uncommented tags is far more complicated than this)  Also, look below for more difficulties you can have on your task to eliminate parent directory references.

## Note 2:

As I have read in your comments to some answers, the problem you want to solve (eliminating `..` references in HTML/XML sources) is not regular.  The reason is that you can have `.` and `..` references embedded in the path strings.  Normally, one must proceed eliminating the `/.` or `./` components of the path, getting a path without `.` (actual directory) references.  Once you have this, you have to eliminate `a/..` references, where `a` is distinct of `..`.  This deals to eliminating occurrences of `a/..`, `a/b/../..`, etc.  But the language that matches `a^i b^i` is not regular (as demonstrated by the pumping lemma ---see google) and you'll need a context independent grammar.

## Note 3:

If you limit the number of `a/b/c/../../..` levels to some maximum bound, you're still able to find a regexp to match this kind of strings, but you can have one example that breaks your regexp and makes it invalid.  Remember, you first have to eliminate the single dot `.` path component (as you can have something like `a/b/./././c/./d/.././e/f/.././../..`.  You will first eliminate the single dot components, leading to: `a/b/c/d/../e/f/../../../..`.  Then you proceed by pairs of `<non ..>/..`, getting `a/b/c/[d/..]/e/f/../../../..` to `a/b/c/e/[f/..]/../../..` -> `a/b/c/[e/..]/../..` -> `a/b/[c/..]/..` -> `a/[b/..]` -> `a`  (you ought to check that all the first components of a pair do exist before being eliminated to be precise) and if you get to an empty path, you will have to change it to `.` to be usable.

I have code to do this process, but it's embedded in some bigger program.  If you are interested, you can access [this code](https://github.com/mojadita/c2html.git). (look at the `rel_path()` routine [here](https://github.com/mojadita/c2html/blob/master/node.c))

You cannot eliminate a `..` element at the beginning of a path (better, that has not a `<non ..>` counterpart), as it refers to outside of the tree, making the reference dependant on the external structure of the tree.